# Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and every map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$. Show that $\pi_1(X, x_0) = 0$ for all $x_0 \in X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Suppose that $X$ is a topological space and every map $S^1 \to X$ extends to a map $D^2 \to X$. Show that $\pi_1(X, x_0) = 0$ for all $x_0 \in X$.

Since for any $f : S^1 \to X$ there exists an extension $g : D^2 \to X$ i.e. $g \mid_{S^1} = f$ we get induced homomorphisms $\iota_* : \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(D^2)$, $f_* : \pi_1(S^1) \to \pi_1(X)$ and $g_* : \pi_1(D^2) \to \pi_1(X)$.

Now since $\pi_1(D^2) = 0$ this would mean that $g_*$ is the zero map so $$f_* = g_* \circ \iota_* = 0$$

which says that the induced map $f_*$ is also the zero map. Can we conclude based on this alone that $\pi_1(X, x_0) = 0$ or is there some other facts we should prove?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we can.

You would like to conclude that any class $\gamma \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$ is zero. This indeed does follow as long as you know that if $\gamma = [f]$ for some $f$ sending $\bullet \in S^1$ to $x_0$, then $f_*: \pi_1(S^1, \bullet) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \to \pi_1(X, x_0)$ sends $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to $\gamma$. And this is immediate from definitions.

Comment: I don't quite follow. It is as if you would like to say that $f_\ast$ is surjective to conclude that every loop $\gamma \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$ is the image of some loop $\alpha \in \pi_1(S^1, \bullet)$? @aрсений-Кряжев-is-with-ukraine

Comment: @Sleep Walker That's right. Can take $\alpha = 1$.